# Certificate Hierarchy shows only intermediate CA and not the Root CA

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I followed the link https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html to create root CA and intermediate CA. Intermediate CA was signed by root CA.

When I check the intermediate CA (below is the output), you can find the issuer and subject are different(I mean root CA signed the intermediate certificate)

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in certs/intermediate.cert.pem  

Certificate:

Data:

    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=IN, ST=Karnataka, L=JP Nager, O=XXX, OU=xxx, CN=abc/emailAddress=abc@xyz.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Jul 14 09:05:19 2016 GMT
        Not After : Jul 12 09:05:19 2026 GMT
    Subject: C=IN, ST=Karnataka, O=XXX, OU=xxx, CN=Ipad Intermidiate Certificate
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        RSA Public Key: (4096 bit)
            Modulus (4096 bit):
                00:c6:44:d6:78:0d:f3:bc:69:8d:31:ce:00:01:8d:
                d4:1b:ee:de:96:16:13:00:1e:f6:0e:7b:00:35:f2:
                57:48:fc:fb:0c:38:9e:0e:d2:67:d0:b9:82:3d:28:
                29:94:0a:95:a2:e2:5e:88:e7:77:cf:23:a3:2d:8a:
                46:fa:d9:a7:c5:41:fc:b9:73:65:03:c1:98:8b:c3:
                0a:e8:dc:4b:c5:cb:2f:5b:97:7a:46:9d:85:74:ae:
                0c:c1:15:7d:58:c5:ea:7f:29:17:aa:e9:34:e9:f4:
                9e:50:bb:ce:f3:59:26:aa:63:cc:f7:d4:03:0b:20:
                83:10:a6:dc:d8:e0:6b:3b:ae:dd:14:20:ec:6a:93:
                5e:83:11:cd:4b:3d:e0:08:a5:fb:b0:27:e3:2e:86:
                45:1e:1c:d6:19:bd:8b:5d:fa:37:18:ad:fd:e2:ce:
                b0:39:8a:5c:5a:d0:1d:46:8b:74:22:35:c0:9f:e7:
                01:c7:0b:50:4f:ab:e2:01:90:3e:c5:d8:15:48:aa:
                fe:4c:96:5e:fb:3f:3a:69:4c:d9:22:2a:5e:4e:39:
                cc:75:0a:14:44:39:e6:5d:1b:f2:97:fc:a5:b1:c0:
                ac:a5:21:49:56:ad:55:e4:08:54:af:17:14:47:f1:
                47:03:4d:ac:c4:02:ae:5f:e8:d6:9c:fe:92:36:e3:
                cd:30:65:60:56:c8:6e:0c:5a:df:08:b9:63:2e:4a:
                d9:c3:af:20:32:81:7b:fa:0a:d6:0d:0c:5c:a0:36:
                9c:fd:0d:d3:64:29:f5:e5:2b:16:86:65:06:7c:fc:
                db:ed:e2:2b:02:5a:ae:53:63:30:48:59:6b:1d:3b:
                5e:68:6e:2b:90:92:df:73:d9:10:1a:73:d0:da:e3:
                4e:49:61:ea:ca:d9:b8:2d:4e:c5:26:e6:38:02:84:
                fb:80:8b:97:55:d1:c2:2d:30:29:0c:25:cb:a4:6b:
                d3:8d:c5:ec:40:76:5e:e5:8e:ed:4b:86:cb:c7:9b:
                d1:3a:89:f3:97:ff:e9:8f:a7:6b:8d:d2:ca:00:cd:
                f0:a7:3d:74:3b:6d:db:6c:d1:2c:f5:89:24:e8:6d:
                7d:fe:f6:56:8e:62:8b:02:a4:5e:27:20:50:18:99:
                c6:4a:38:70:8b:0a:bb:aa:16:b5:4d:54:29:29:46:
                44:dd:4d:53:cd:82:8f:97:8b:a8:6e:17:33:6f:15:
                16:08:31:e2:d7:bc:7e:46:a9:58:a9:2e:26:14:fb:
                7d:38:30:10:9e:5d:2c:8e:6d:bf:f5:03:ed:bf:37:
                b6:0c:9d:35:83:84:76:11:16:e2:14:f2:47:d5:7e:
                1b:a2:da:74:ff:e1:e0:b2:07:f5:9d:4c:08:fa:c1:
                5c:8f:1d
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            D5:58:FE:D4:78:8A:93:77:28:65:04:D6:41:DB:A1:B0:FC:3E:37:F2
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:91:8E:47:44:08:F0:30:70:3A:9F:46:4C:C5:C9:D6:0C:17:D3:26:5D
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    90:80:df:ee:2d:37:33:ea:02:fc:95:dc:e5:04:e9:c2:75:4c:
    85:39:a1:ee:86:94:13:6d:94:75:4d:35:be:2a:45:d6:50:7c:
    e9:ec:49:51:80:6c:c2:3e:5d:ea:e5:fb:c2:d5:1a:c4:ad:be:
    58:24:8a:c0:9f:8a:d3:df:5c:02:94:bb:e5:c0:cf:8c:76:7b:
    9c:24:b2:af:37:fe:a2:a8:e3:6c:9b:bc:7b:2f:88:f0:99:1e:
    3e:b7:40:76:c4:64:41:b8:70:67:09:ce:51:f2:16:b8:af:23:
```

Output of root ca certificate

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ca/certs/ca.cert.pem

Certificate: 

Data:
        Version:3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:d1:4f:18:94:21:32:f1:c2
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=IN, ST=Karnataka, L=JP Nager, O=XXX, OU=xxx, CN=abc/emailAddress=abc@xyz.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 14 07:07:30 2016 GMT
            Not After : Jul  9 07:07:30 2036 GMT
        Subject: C=IN, ST=Karnataka, L=JP Nager, O=XXX, OU=xxx, CN=abc/emailAddress=abc@xyz.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus (4096 bit):
                    00:d4:f5:ac:3b:8f:85:d6:2b:e9:fc:d8:5c:7b:99:
                    85:70:2d:96:c3:fc:5c:25:79:07:a0:62:f6:2e:aa:
                    8a:5f:62:18:2c:3d:c1:18:9c:8d:46:d1:c1:da:7f:
                    7a:92:02:bc:31:86:d6:e2:19:f3:b1:6f:39:73:1d:
                    48:df:3a:a4:a3:8e:3a:b2:1a:46:50:6e:e5:af:b3:
                    a2:c2:eb:c7:73:70:2b:06:02:e8:2b:65:72:76:90:
                    1e:22:54:42:07:c6:2a:d5:4e:aa:4d:f8:29:b6:88:
                    e7:66:c8:e2:06:30:c1:05:4a:a1:5a:ec:90:d0:e2:
                    1a:15:69:d7:18:89:9a:d1:21:43:62:46:00:68:fd:
                    cd:bb:21:be:1b:4d:3e:7c:14:8b:b1:10:e5:c4:f8:
                    82:13:a8:b8:be:d8:99:ae:14:d8:46:c6:cb:e5:1a:
                    77:e7:a5:e4:b4:0f:64:14:72:91:d3:b0:33:98:26:
                    d4:22:ac:84:f0:57:c7:b6:ff:f2:18:14:e9:a3:d3:
                    ce:46:ac:ee:a9:3b:a3:a8:75:c6:62:90:29:3f:fc:
                    91:e8:e9:d4:86:2a:50:53:fd:ff:44:5e:32:4a:40:
                    67:84:64:b5:c4:dd:51:74:0c:d6:93:2d:f9:c3:34:
                    66:4c:62:b4:cf:5d:ee:d7:2a:ce:22:15:90:56:ac:
                    e0:95:1e:81:50:31:51:8c:70:26:ae:34:55:eb:e0:
                    58:14:8a:91:b5:79:aa:b5:51:3a:14:99:40:8d:68:
                    5f:ab:63:7d:bb:9a:c7:ae:66:64:3c:b0:2b:36:90:
                    43:b7:7c:d8:42:a2:33:95:6f:c4:cf:7d:1c:7c:87:
                    af:d6:4d:50:73:91:ce:90:69:d4:51:3d:f3:d3:07:
                    92:fa:b0:d7:b0:e6:59:db:b8:de:7f:6b:7f:4b:4c:
                    71:69:49:a5:83:72:67:95:d6:2b:e5:d9:d3:e9:12:
                    43:c2:68:1b:37:85:3f:a7:2e:3e:d0:78:06:29:85:
                    31:f8:1e:2e:43:d5:ae:55:3c:80:38:1c:e0:84:61:
                    37:84:b4:8e:e8:30:48:da:2a:95:2b:0c:6c:2c:15:
                    ef:96:af:12:f9:4c:c2:96:f8:86:c4:d5:db:cc:6b:
                    4c:92:ca:39:ed:b6:72:e5:d2:78:24:38:c1:e1:b6:
                    bd:f0:7c:50:e6:c8:ec:ca:f4:ae:a6:52:0a:57:3b:
                    87:f8:1c:c1:f1:22:28:5a:5b:f1:c9:3b:68:70:32:
                    6c:e3:96:60:eb:70:64:79:38:d9:93:42:d9:38:2c:
                    be:42:02:23:6d:09:ab:56:6b:fd:5c:c8:dc:1e:de:
                    6f:fe:a7:69:2e:65:61:1d:54:6b:d5:6b:93:ac:89:
                    a3:20:47
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                91:8E:47:44:08:F0:30:70:3A:9F:46:4C:C5:C9:D6:0C:17:D3:26:5D
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
               keyid:91:8E:47:44:08:F0:30:70:3A:9F:46:4C:C5:C9:D6:0C:17:D3:26:5D
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        20:b7:52:b6:0d:12:34:26:fe:b6:f3:20:7e:83:71:2c:a9:48:
        4e:08:6f:87:a7:9d:89:38:a7:c1:f2:dd:f9:a3:54:87:24:09:
        99:28:d8:5e:8a:a5:65:3d:1c:ee:82:68:cb:6c:5d:9d:51:3a:
        06:ab:ea:b2:10:7c:6e:d8:f7:a5:1e:ed:19:18:2b:d0:36:93:
        f5:e6:c1:00:b5:9c:b5:61:c9:13:52:6b:59:f7:da:ae:9a:c4:
        ad:cb:6b:f4:07:22:45:69:c4:9c:a7:50:b7:47:4b:bc:52:73:
        e9:7a:aa:8c:6c:ec:0f:ba:86:93:48:50:d3:32:4e:dc:df:96:
        20:41:e0:47:c0:d4:cb:c2:54:9e:21:54:36:77:df:69:e3:0d:
        3e:19:ee:a3:a4:d7:3d:d0:bb:63:a6:80:27:57:54:84:20:17:
        79:3e:c8:19:4b:7e:1d:d4:cc:75:a2:9e:48:a6:8f:23:c2:a5:
        a0:30:7d:a6:83:e6:14:9a:0e:91:58:de:71:46:0b:d2:ee:27:
        d7:61:31:f9:2e:f7:c2:fa:19:76:21:a0:6a:46:b0:34:1f:25:
        f0:ef:7f:b7:12:11:46:ec:28:de:b8:a2:f5:4e:ab:6d:a6:eb:
        2e:77:f5:74:e9:b0:c0:58:99:c9:c8:97:8a:92:1a:95:d1:21:
        9a:42:b5:df:f5:df:34:82:a8:2d:9d:41:4b:56:73:4f:84:dd:
        fa:0d:b7:6a:9a:0f:e7:09:7a:0d:b7:d8:6e:97:a5:0e:bc:49:
        6a:aa:7e:87:05:f2:73:00:5a:7b:ec:f5:2a:0f:04:c8:72:40:
        24:d1:29:1d:d6:a9:ab:2c:09:4c:3c:9d:7e:a3:3e:c5:49:04:
        71:8c:88:10:c7:dd:f7:9b:05:6f:e5:bf:e1:de:d1:b4:59:a8:
        4c:ef:37:30:d2:71:fd:a6:7c:d6:88:6e:bc:73:ed:99:7e:0e:
        ff:04:4b:52:e9:30:44:36:db:7e:0d:31:86:13:95:64:14:b4:
        44:95:0a:c4:6f:13:06:c8:07:a4:13:fe:f8:eb:5b:27:44:b0:
        26:71:97:b5:48:ba:73:1a:f4:53:65:bd:bd:cd:d5:5f:9b:64:
        a8:ab:71:d0:9d:ad:a8:a0:fb:8f:a7:37:1d:f7:62:3e:a0:69:
        7c:25:4a:fb:5d:3f:81:9f:7b:2a:40:0b:35:90:5b:47:8d:55:
        36:c7:0f:8c:cb:53:62:f1:ae:5f:13:74:52:eb:dc:21:01:8f:
        c6:6e:35:25:ae:2a:d1:60:9e:98:51:ca:2e:b8:0c:3c:00:db:
        7c:a2:82:b2:97:71:99:78:77:84:8d:91:8e:de:5b:80:61:99:
        70:c5:56:3f:12:e8:ff:e0**
```

Now, when I access a webserver which has the certificate signed by the intermediate CA ,the browser throws error saying the certificate is not valid the reason being in the Certificate Hierarchy root CA information is not there.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Have you included the root CA cert in the trust store used by the browser? Note that different browsers have different definitions of what they consider to be the "trust store".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Yes I have included the root CA in my firefox browser.Note the certificate was signed by intermediate CA.
Expected Behaviour:- I should able to access the site without any certificate error since i have added the root ca in my trust store of the browser.
Actual behaviour:- Browser throws an error even-though the root CA is added in the trust store.

Comment: Does server present the intermediate CA cert as part of the handshake? You need to configure the chain (intermediate + end-entity) in your server to complete the chain.